# Store vim external command result lines into a VimL array, to make a little custom autocomplete

Tags: vimscript, autocompletion

This little snippet aims to make a little autocomplete script in VimL. the first code:

```
cat % | grep function | sed  's/(/ /g' | awk '{print $3}'
```

list all the method inside a php class. For example the output of this command could be:

```
__construct
__toString
foo
bar
```

If I send to complete function an array

```
call complete(col('.'), ["__construct", "__toString", "foo", "bar"])
```

I can see this menu:

[image]

So the final question is, ... how can I transform this:

```
__construct
__toString
foo
bar
```

into this `["__construct", "__toString", "foo", "bar"]`?

Here my wrong code:

```
inoremap <F5> <C-R>=CustomComplete()<CR>
func! CustomComplete()
    let l:functions = system("cat % | grep function | sed  's/(/ /g' | awk '{print $3}'")
    call complete(col('.'), l:functions)
    return ''
endfunc
```

Comment: Couple of tangential points: **a).** Shouldn't it be `$2`? **b).** You don't need to use `grep` and `sed` in addition to `awk`: `awk -F '[( ]' '/function/ {print $3}'` does the same thing as your pipeline. The [vim-slime](https://github.com/jpalardy/vim-slime) guy even suggests [replacing grep with awk entirely](http://blog.jpalardy.com/posts/skip-grep-use-awk/)!

Comment: Ah, I see why you're using `$3`. Disregard query **a).** Sorry!

Answer (score 3):

You can `split()` `system()` result into a list, or you can directly use `systemlist()`.

BTW, I wouldn't have used a sequence of external programs. Looks like your code is equivalent (untested) to the following which I suspect to be more efficient than cat + grep + sed + awk:

```
let lines_with_functions = filter(getline(1, '$'), 'v:val =~ "function"')
let fnames = map(lines_with_functions, 'matchstr(v:val, "\\vfunction\\s+\\zs\\I\\i*\\ze\\s*\\(")')
```

Comment: when I press F5 is just si pasted in the file "cat: % No such file or directory"

Comment: Indeed, you would have needed `expand('%:p')` instead of the string `'%'`. But honestly, we don't need `system()` here.